# React propTypes mixing function with requirement

Tags: reactjs, properties, react-proptypes

So I have a prop in `propTypes` set to a function. However, I also want to specify that the value passed to that prop must be a string.

Current:

```
propTypes: {
  user: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (props.user != undefined) console.log('Error');
  },
  x: React.propTypes.nonNegative
}
```

Want to also include:

```
propTypes:{
  user: React.PropTypes.string
}
```

Is there a way to require the value for the `user` props to be a string while still using a function?

Comment: your example is not very clear. user must be a string but you are trying to access `x` property, so it seems that your props is an object...

Comment: Edited. The `props.x` was leftover from something else but is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

So just test its type with `typeof` :

```js
propTypes: {
  user: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (typeof props != 'string') {
      return new Error(
          'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
          ' `' + componentName + '`. It must be a string.'
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's say I already have other logic inside the function. Is there any other way I can avoid bunching together if statements inside the function? It feels a bit messy.

Comment: This is not very clear because you post small questions. Tell us what the final goal of this, show us what you want.